# How do I get specific element in jQuery.each loop

Tags: jquery

I need to get the div containing the street address within the list. The div has a class called address ( div class="address" )

I cannot use jQuery("#storeList li .address"), because there are other elements I need to acces as well.

I have the following code:

```
jQuery("#storeList li").each(function() {
  var n = jQuery(this.address).text(); // <- This does not work
  alert(n);
});
```

How do I access each DIV element of type Address?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
jQuery("#storeList li").each(function() {
  var n = jQuery(this).find(".address").text(); // <- This works
  alert(n);
});
```

Comment: better to prefix the selectors with the node name also - jQuery(this).find("div.address")

Comment: It depends. If you prefix the selector with the node name, you cannot change the structure of the elements (e.g. replace a div by a span) without having to change the javascript code. On the other hand, jQuery might select the element faster if you use node selectors.

Comment: Yes, node selectors will select an element faster. Conversely with CSS if you make your selector too specific, it slows down the selector process.

Comment: I spent about an hour trying to build a similar query to no avail. It kept giving me objects and messages about "v" is not a function (I was using the standard "i" and "v" notation as is taught with JavaScript). I finally found this post. Eureka! My issue was that I was doing $('this') instead of $(this) (I didn't need quotes). Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#storeList li').each(function() 
{
  var n = $(this).find('div.address').html(); 
  alert(n);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
jQuery("#storeList li:has(.address) .address").each(function() {
    alert(this.innerHTML);
});
```

An alternative that avoids using a second query. As a jQuery newbie I don't know what the tradeoffs really are though.

Comment: That's nice if you only care about address, but not if you have more fields, or what to handle li without addresses. Also, you don't need `li:has(.address) .address`, it's the same but slower than `li .address` - you're selecting the `.address`, so you know it's there.

Comment: Is that cynical? I'm just trying to help... I didn't down vote it, by the way, though it's understandable.

Comment: I _was_ being sarcastic and I did assume you down-voted it. Apologies. I really can't see the point of that. Why would anyone offer a different possibility?